# Can I use IPython embed() to change the state of a function?

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to embed an IPython session inside a function such that it makes changes to the code as if it were in global namespace? If not, why? And are there alternatives?

From the entry on the IPython wiki regarding [embedding an IPython session from the inside of a Python script](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython):

> It’s important to note that the code run in the embedded IPython shell will not change the state of your code and variables, unless the shell is contained within the global namespace.

A small example of this behavior is changing a variable from an IPython session, which is inside the Python REPL:

```
>>> from IPython import embed
>>> a = 12
>>> embed()

In [1]: a = 13

In [2]: exit()

>>> a
13
```

However when embedding inside a function:

```
>>> from IPython import embed
>>> def f():
...     x = 2
...     embed()
...     print(x)
... 
>>> f()

In [1]: x = 3

In [2]:                                                                  

2
```

Although I don't understand why it must be so (design choice? technical problems?) I would like to change my code with IPython outside the global namespace, i.e. a function, which should be allowed behavior, considering that most well structured programs will leave as little as possible to the global namespace (in my case I'm trying to change my `main()` function).

Comment: It clearly says in the docs that this is not possible. What else are you asking?

Comment: If it helps, [here's the source code for `embed()`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/80aee3f6e7f24c6f48a7a4d8b9878aec16332186/IPython/terminal/embed.py#L339)

Comment: @smac89 Did you see this part? *"If not, why? And are there alternatives?*"

Comment: The _why_ part is answered by the documentation. If you are not satisfied with that, then you can look in the source code and make a PR to the ipython people to enable this feature. As for alternatives, I have no idea; You are trying to bypass a well defined behaviour, therefore any solution will most likely be a hack and may not work 100%.

Comment: @smac89 Where does it say why in the documentation? I only saw it say that it's not possible.

Comment: I don't mean that they explained the reason why; I just meant that the docs say it is not supported. If you want to know the design choices behind that, then you probably need to ask an ipython developer or look in the source code. The fact that they took the time to mention it probably means there must be a good reason why.

Comment: Before asking the developers something I decided to ask the community, because the first thing that came to mind when i first saw `embed()` was "can I use this to change the state of the code?", and I thought this might have been asked before, especially when they say that `embed()` couldn't do it, for whatever reasons, but something else could, especially knowing that there are debuggers out there that could contain such a feature (yet I found none unfortunately), hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this! This is just a PoC of how to hack around this design feature.

*You are likely not going to find a solution that doesn't involve something similar. But I'll just leave this here so you can see how ugly a potential workaround could be.*

```
from IPython import embed

def main():
  global g
  g = 40
  embed()
  print (g)

main()
```

Now inside the IPython repl, we do:

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 27 2021, 00:33:24)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: g += 2

In [2]: globals().update(dict(g=g))

In [3]:
```

The output:

```
42
```

Not only is it hacky, but it also touches the global namespace which according to you, is not desirable.

Comment: Yes I see where you are getting at, but unfortunately that isn't as simple as fitting an `embed()` onto it, as you would have to guess beforehand which variables you were looking to modify, and it would still only modify the global namespace.